# Extract ID number from String using REGEXP_SUBSTR in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column NAME(VARCHAR2) which stores the ID numbers of the accounts.

```
ROW_NBR  NAME
----      -------------------------------------
1         JOHN SMITH ACCT_ID 123762839 PTY LTD
2         HELLOWORLD PTY LDT ACCT_ID: 123 762 839 CORP LTD
3         GLOBAL FUND PER_ID 32 123 456 789 ACCT_ID 989 190 293 CORP
4         WORLD CORP PER_ID: 32 123 456 789 ACCT_ID: 243 130 222 PTY
```

I'm trying to extract the 9 digit ACCT_ID, remove the 'ACCT_ID%' string, and store it into a column with VARCHAR2(09).

The results should look like this:

```
ROW_NBR  NAME                                     ACCT_ID
----     -------------------------------------    ----------
1        JOHN SMITH PTY LTD                       123762839
2        HELLOWORLD PTY LDT CORP LTD              123712833
3        GLOBAL FUND PER_ID 32 123 456 789 CORP   989190293
4        WORLD CORP PER_ID: 32 123 456 789 PTY    243130222
```

So far I have been able to extract the ACCT_ID, provided that the number does not have spaces.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, 'ACCT_ID \s*\d+'), '\d+') FROM DUAL;
```

This SQL works but only for for the 1st Record, as I can get the 9 digit ACCT_ID. How do I do this for the rest of the records? I can't get it to extract just the ACCT_ID value without any spaces (eg. '989190293').

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
with t (ROW_NBR,  NAME) as (
    select 1 ,'JOHN SMITH ACCT_ID 123762839 PTY LTD'                       from dual union all
    select 2 ,'HELLOWORLD PTY LDT ACCT_ID: 123 762 839 CORP LTD'           from dual union all
    select 3 ,'GLOBAL FUND PER_ID 32 123 456 789 ACCT_ID 989 190 293 CORP' from dual union all
    select 4 ,'WORLD CORP PER_ID: 32 123 456 789 ACCT_ID: 243 130 222 PTY' from dual
)
-- Test data above. Actual solution start here --

select 
  replace(regexp_replace(name, '.*ACCT_ID\D*([0-9 ]+).*','\1'),' ')
from t;
```

Produces:

```
123762839
123762839
989190293
243130222
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\s*\d)+` - or perhaps, better, `(\s*\d){9}` just in case for some reason there are further digits after the account number.

Not tested, but something like this:

```
SELECT row_nbr, name, REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAME, 'ACCT_ID:? ((\s*\d){9})', 1, 1, null, 1) 
FROM    <SOMETHING_SURELY_NOT_FROM_DUAL!>
```

Two notes: (1) Your inputs have : after ACCT_ID in a couple of cases and they don't have it in the other cases. Fixed by adding `:?` in the search pattern. (2) The output will preserve the spaces in the input; if that is not desired, you may wrap within `replace( ..., ' ')`.